# UILabel Text Strikethrough with Color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I am using the following code to strike through the text

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributeString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:(text ? text : @"")];
[attributeString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName
                        value:@2
                        range:NSMakeRange(0, [attributeString length])];

label.attributedText = attributeString;
```

The text has white color so the strikethrough line is also white. I would like to change that to red. How can I do so?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the [NSAttributedString UIKit Additions Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011688-CH1-SW16), you can set the

```
NSStrikethroughColorAttributeName
```

attribute to an `UIColor` of your choice.

Comment: Thank you. This did it   [attributeString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, [attributeString length])];

Answer (score 11):

Add "NSStrikethroughColorAttributeName" attribute to the string

```
[attributedString addAttributes:@{NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)
                              , NSStrikethroughColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor]
                              , NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor yellowColor]}
```

Documentation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: This page is nolonger available

Answer (score 9):

**SWIFT 3.x**

To strikethrough a text label with color you need 2 attributes, one for the  NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName one for the NSStrikethroughColorAttributeName. I find it more readable.

```
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "0,91 €")
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value: NSNumber(value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue), range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.red, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))
```

Answer (score 9):

**SWIFT 4.2**

@llker Baltaci 's answer update for Swift 4.2

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "0,91 €")
attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle, value: NSNumber(value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue), range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))
attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughColor, value: UIColor.darkGray, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))
```

Answer (score 5):

**In Swift:**

```
attributeString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
```

Comment: Please indent code blocks (use four spaces or select the code & click the `{}` button on the editor toolbar).